# cordova- adb 1.0.32 gives error "Failed to install apk to emulator" where adb1.0.31 succeeds

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

Running `cordova emulate android` gives the following error-

`Error: Failed to install apk to emulator: Error executing "adb -s emulator-5554 install -r "C:/work/projects/cordova/projectName/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk"":`

The error message is not actually correct because the new apk is deployed to the emulator (i have performed minor changes and the apk is updated on emulator), but the app is not started.

When I manually run the adb command that is shown in the error message i get a windows dialog saying that adb.exe has stopped responding. No error msg on the command line. Although the app on the emulator has again updated (so installation is working) and can be manually run from the emulator.

When I copy adb version 1.0.31 (exe and two dlls) over the top of version 1.0.32 in `\platform-tools` it all runs as expected- loads apk and starts app, no errors, regardless of whether i use cordova commands or adb command directly.

Has anyone had this issue with adb1.0.32 and or have a work solution? I have a workaround which is to use 1.0.31, but I would like to know what the issue is.